# .less files are not appear in Nuxt 3 build

Tags: css, build, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a nuxt 3 app, where i want to set global styles via .less files.

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
css: [
    "@/assets/less/main.less"
  ],
```

If i run `yarn run dev` everything works fine, but when i run
`yarn run build` (nuxt build) and `yarn run preview`(nuxt preview) the .less files are just not there. For some reason the build doesnt contain any of the styles from the .less files.

I tried to add the `less-loader` package (although as i know its not needed in nuxt3).
I guess the problem is around the difference of `NODE_ENV production / develop`,but im not sure how or what should i config to get the build involve the .less files.

here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "analyze": "nuxt analyze",
    "cleanup": "nuxt cleanup"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^11.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "less-loader": "^11.1.0",
    "line-clamp": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.10",
    "vue": "^3.2.40"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue-3": "0.4.13",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-disqus": "^5.1.0",
    "vue-gtag": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-next-masonry": "1.1.3",
    "vue-tweet": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install less in the dependencies not in devDependencies